# Proper tense in "I read the documentation but I didn’t find any information about requirements"

Tags: tense, present-perfect, past-simple

> I read the documentation but I didn’t find any information about requirements.

Is it right to use the simple past here? Or should I say it like this:

> I've read the documentation but I haven’t found any information about requirements.

Or maybe like this:

> I've read the documentation but I didn’t find any information about requirements.

Could you please explain which of the above variants is the right choice and why?

Comment: All three are acceptable. Personally, I find the first to be the most simple and direct.

Answer (score 1):

All the provided sentences make sense. 
The first one is simple and clear.

A small comment regarding "about requirements." While that may be fine, these choices strike me as slightly more natural sounding. It depends on the context.

> - about the requirements.
> - about what the requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is directly about common query for you.
Simply and easily can be told with no emphasis generally in tense. 
Present perfect needs emphasis to make it and third sentence too however all of them are correct Englishly.